# Is there a way to change the Docusign UI language setting through API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using embedded signing and it seems it will not detect the browse language.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `supportedLanguage` inside `emailNotification` for each signer in the API. Details are available at [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/recipientEmailNotification)

```
"signers": [{
                    "email": "email@gmail.com",
                    "clientUserId": "1111",
                    "emailNotification": {
                        "supportedLanguage":"de"
                    }
                 ...
```

Comment: That is very helpful! (I've upvoted it) But do you know anyway to do with the UI language settings?

Comment: It should respond to the browser settings, is Signing page not changing based on your browser settings?

Comment: It is NOT changing, :(